# Node.js Promises in nested callbacks in Promises in Promises not resolving

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, resolve

I have the below code that is not resolving.
f2 resolves so I will not add that code, it is f1 I have an issue with.

I call the function and it gets to the inner most if, it calls the function "find", which performs function `findId`, that returns the Id perfectly fine, it then performs `editId` but it does not resolve the `document replaced` + true which I know it gets to as the context log appears.

Expected behavior:

This should resolve back up to the top promise and reach `context.done()` but it does not

This may be a simple issue in terms of where I place new promise etc but I have been struggling with the structure of this for a while.

Thanks for any insight.

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    var documentUrl = xyz;
    client.readDocument(documentUrl, (err, a) => {

        var f1 = fun1(a,b,c);
        var f2 = fun2(a,b,c);

        Promise.all([f1, f2]).then(function(results){ //parallel
            context.log(results[0], results[1]);
            context.done();
        });
    });
}

function fun1 (a,b,c){
if (a[0].stuff.length > 0) {
    var stuffArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < a[0].stuff.length; i++) {
        if (a[0].stuff[i].morestuff !== null && a[0].stuff[i].otherstuff !== null) {
            if (a[0].stuff[i].Id== null) {
            var Id = a[0].id + '_' + i;
                var find = findId (a, Id, function(res){
                    context.log ("findFeedback: found");
                            context.log(res);                            
                            editId(context, res);
                });
                stuffArray.push(find);                
            }
        } else {
            stuffArray.push(i + " shouldn't have Id");
        }    
    }
    return Promise.all(stuffArray);
} else {
    return ('No stuff');
}
}
function findId(a, Id, callback) {    
    var documentUrl = myUrl/id;
        client.readDocument(documentUrl, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return(err);
                }
            } else {
                callback(result);
             }
        });
}

function editId(context, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var documentUrl = myUrl/res.otherId;
        client.readDocument(documentUrl, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code == HttpStatusCodes.NOTFOUND) {
                    context.log('Post does not exist');
                    resolve('Post does not exist');
                } else {
                    context.log(err);
                    resolve(err);
                }
            } else {
                context.log('Post exists');
                // here i edit some stuff which works fine                            
                client.replaceDocument(documentUrl, result, (err, result) => {
                if(err) {
                    context.log(err);
                    resolve('Document replaced ' + false);
                } else {
                    context.log('replaced document ' + result);
                    resolve('Document replaced ' + true);
                    // This is where my context log ends it does not resolve back up 
                }
        });                

             }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: string concatenation with bool? also where is fun1?

Comment: I don't understand what that means sorry - I'm quite new to this!

Comment: you are resolving `'Document replaced ' + true` which is string and bool which doesn't seem correct

Comment: Hmm that has worked elsewhere for me I'm pretty sure - I have just tred making it all string and it still has the same issue, I believe it is to do with the resolving of promises.

Comment: Apologies I have edited `function f1` to `function fun1`

Comment: Try catching your errors for an indication of what is wrong.

Comment: @mjrcodin not sure exactly how to implement that - my function ends just it doesn't wait for `editId` to finish before doing `return Promise.all(stuffArray);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findId` requires `return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { });` wrapped around it.

And then you can call `editId` within `findId` and replace `callback(result)` with `resolve(editId(context, result));`

After that replace the `var find` in `fun1` with `var find = findId (a, id)` and remove the callback requirement from `findId`

Answer (score 2):

The point here is to make your code consistent.

I think you should wrap all of your callback function to Promise. That will make your code cleaner, easier and not become a spaghetti.

I don't have enough context to test. So I just try to refactor your code a little. Hope it helps you in some aspect.

the findId function should return a promise instead of using callback:

```
function findId(Id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var documentUrl = myUrl / id;
    client.readDocument(documentUrl, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

in the fun1 function, you have async code in a for loop. It won't work because async code will not wait until it has result for you. So I refactor by push the id you need to call `findId` into `stuffArr`. Then, I map those ids into a list of promise function `findId`. By doing that, we can use Promise.all to wait for all the promises to process.

```
function fun1(a, b, c) {
  if (a[0].stuff.length > 0) {
    var stuffArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < a[0].stuff.length; i++) {
      if (
        a[0].stuff[i].morestuff !== null &&
        a[0].stuff[i].otherstuff !== null
      ) {
        if (a[0].stuff[i].Id == null) {
          var Id = a[0].id + "_" + i;
          var promise = findId(Id)
                .then(res => editId(context, res))
                .catch(err => i + " Some error");
          stuffArray.push(promise);
        } else {
          // don't know what you want to do here
        }
      } else {
        stuffArray.push(i + " shouldn't have Id");
      }
    }

    return Promise.all(stuffFindPromises);
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve("No stuff");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't want spaghetti, use async and await.

Comment: async, await or promise are both OK, I think. The point here is to stick on 1 thing only. I have explained above. If he has the idea of using promise, should make everything promise so that he can easily debug and read the code.

Comment: My point is that using async and await would eliminate the nesting, reduce the code size by 30%, and make the code easier to read.

Comment: @StevenSpungin There's a single `then` call in the code that you could replace by an `await`. Hardly makes up 30%.

Comment: @DatTran thanks for replying - I have replicated this code but it seems to yield the same results (it ends on "replaced document" - the issue is 1) I want to push 'i + "shouldnt have Id" ' into `stuffArray` back up to the first promise as part of results[0] and not push that into the findId 2) I do want to resolve from `editId` before finishing fun1

Comment: @StevenSpungin I tried to implement awaits but by using azure functions I needed to republish all my code using v2 which is in beta

Comment: @Bergi FYI by using async, you don't have to return Promise.resolve(...), you can just return your value, and you can also throw exceptions instead of calling reject.  And you make it obvious that the function is async. And no nesting.  I will go so far to say that unless you have restrictions to not use the async/await syntax, it's foolish do otherwise.  It's just sugar anyway as promises are used under the hood.

Comment: Its also common practice to use map() instead of for(...) and return the promises in the map function.  Then Promise.all() on the returned value.

Comment: @StevenSpungin azure requires v2 beta to use async/await and it is buggy so have had to stick to v1

Comment: @DatTran thanks so much - this works now, I have found another solution I will post below as an answer too